# Bootstrap text not visible in input on iOS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a small website with Bootstrap. All is ok on Windows, Andoid or Mac.

On iPhone (iOS) the text in input are not visible, as if the color was white or text is without opacity.
I try to disabled webkit-appearance or fix color with webkit-text-fill-color but I get the same result.

The shortcut url is available here : http://www.app.solutionssuretesecurite.com/

Comment: I guess, the short URL doesn't work properly.

Comment: You can't access to the website ?

Comment: Yeah, your short URL redirects me to the main page of link shorter service at least on Chrome.

Comment: Strange, I remove the shortcut url

Comment: you should customize form-control, i.e control-form or anything else, and customize by yourself

Comment: What is the interess to use bootstrap design if I need to customize it by myself ? This problem is only on iOS not on all platform

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with css. But the point to remember is to mark it as "!important". For example the code below is a css code that works only for IOS. So you can overwrite the bootstrap css codes.

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
  .your-class {
    opacity:1 !important;
  }
}

@supports not (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS for other than iOS devices */ 
  .your-class {
    opacity:1 !important;
  }
}
```

So you have a custom style definition for a problem that only happens with IOS devices.

Comment: Thanks, finally find the problem, it was due to a custom line-height that Safari dislike